# How can I apply multiple filter to array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I can just filter by input text that comes from "searchTerm" state. but I want to include "selectedOption" dropdown input to the filter. how can I use multiple filters for an array?

btw I'm using react-select for dropdown menu.

```js
const Positions = ({ positions }: dataProps) => {

const options: any = [
  { value: "Canada", label: "Canada" },
  { value: "Italy", label: "Italy" },
];

const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const filteredPositions = useMemo(() => {
    if (!searchTerm) return positions;
    return positions.filter(({ id, ...other }: any) => {
      const lowerCasedSearchTerm: string = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

      return Object.values(other)
        .map((v: any) => v.toLowerCase())
        .some((v: any) => v.includes(lowerCasedSearchTerm));
    });
  }, [searchTerm, positions]);

  return (

             <input
                  type="search"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            <div className={styles.positions__item}>
              <Select
                defaultValue={selectedOption}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                options={options}
              />
              <Select
                defaultValue={selectedOption}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                options={options}
              />

   {filteredPositions?.map((position: any, index: any) => (
            <div key={position.position}>
              <SinglePosition
                category={position.category}
                type={position.type}
                position={position.position}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: You can do it like this `some((v: any) => v.includes(lowerCasedSearchTerm) || v.includes(selectedOption))`

Comment: thank you but didn't work :( I tried with ```selectedOption.value``` still same.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output. It will be easier that way.

Answer (score 1):

Check this please.

```
const filteredPositions = useMemo(() => {
if (!(searchTerm || selectedOption)) return positions;
return positions.filter(({ id, ...other }: any) => {
  const lowerCasedSearchTerm: string = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

  return Object.values(other)
    .map((v: any) => v.toLowerCase())
    .some((v: any) => v.includes(lowerCasedSearchTerm) || v.includes(selectedOption));
});
 }, [searchTerm, positions, selectedOption]);
```

Comment: thank you but didn't filter selectedoption :( just worked on search input.

Comment: Could you please, provide the code on a live editor like codesandbox, So we can debug. https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I put it on index.js and app.js files. data comes from sanity no problem with searchTerm but dropdown doesn't filter.

Comment: If you don't mind, let's have a meeting so, I can debug the code in your environment.

Comment: im not available right now. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const filteredPositions = useMemo(() => {
    if (!searchTerm) return positions;
    return positions.filter(({ id, ...other }: any) => {
      const lowerCasedSearchTerm: string = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

      return Object.values(other)
        .map((v: any) => v.toLowerCase())
        .some((v: any) => v.includes(lowerCasedSearchTerm) || v.includes(selectedOption.value.toLowerCase()));
    });
  }, [searchTerm, positions]);
```

Since, we are converting everything into lowercase, we need to convert selected option as well.